# Drush bootstrap fail - wrong MySQL username

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop

`drush sql-connect` produces valid, working MySQL credentials:

> mysql --user=drupaluser --password= --database=core_20161101
>   --host=127.0.0.1 --port=33067

So does `drush status`:

> Database driver        :  mysql
>   Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1
>   Database port          :  33067
>   Database username      :  drupaluser
>   Database name          :  core_20161101

However `drush -d uinf admin` and anything else that needs to read the database fails with:

> [...] sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.35 sec, 4.88 MB]
>   [notice] Executing: mysql
>   --defaults-extra-file=/private/tmp/drush_dZeMQb --database=core_20161101 --host=127.0.0.1 --port=33067 --silent  < /private/tmp/drush_Tu2o2g   ERROR 1045 (28000): **Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost'** (using password: YES) Bootstrap to phase 1. [0.37
>   sec, 4.88 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.54 sec, 6.68 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Bootstrap to phase 5. [0.54 sec, 6.68 MB]
>   [bootstrap] Command user-information needs a higher bootstrap level to
>   run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal
>   environment to run this command. [0.54 sec, 6.68 MB]
>   [error] The drush command 'uinf admin' could not be executed. [0.54
>   sec, 6.68 MB]
>   [error] Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database. 
>   [...]

Note the username is wrong, root@localhost, not drupaluser@127.0.0.1.

Any ideas why it would be switching to the wrong username?

**Versions:**
Acquia Dev Desktop 2 (built Sep 5 2016)
PHP 5.5.33 (as set by Dev Desktop)
Drush 8.0.5
Mac OS 10.11.6

Comment: I think drush is not working properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't happen to have a `~/.my.cnf` file (which sets the user to root)? MySQL will read that file after the file specified by `--defaults-extra-file`, and "If multiple instances of a given option are found, the last instance takes precedence".

Comment: Thanks - I'd completely forgotten I'd set that up (and had looked everywhere for an answer but not seen anyone mention it…)

Comment: You just saved me!  I was struggling to figure out why drush wasn't working and this was it.  It was a leftover my.cnf file was a previous installation of mysql.