# How to use drush locally with Acquia Dev Desktop2 and upgrade core

Tags: drush, updating, acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud

I just a new project in Drupal 8 and it's hosted on Acquias cloud using Dev Desktop 2 (DD later on). 
Now the project is working fine, but i can't use drush at all, as the settings.php is generated by DD as is the code for the DB conneciton.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR']) && file_exists($_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/cld_my_site_default.inc')) {
  require $_SERVER['DEVDESKTOP_DRUPAL_SETTINGS_DIR'] . '/cld_my_site_default.inc';
}
```

I found a post [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192770/cant-get-drush-to-work-after-moving-to-acquia-dev-desktop) where the suggested method was to create a `local.settings.php` and in it paste the contents of the file `cld_my_site_default.inc` but that's a dead end as i can't access that file.

Anyone knows how do i setup drush so i can update the core, as per this [tut](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-drush).

Answer (score 0):

in Acquia Dev Desktop application,  when your project is selected there is a small
icon on the right-hand side. If you press it will open CMD and the correct path will be autoselected. Drush up will work there.

Good Luck